# Is it Possible to Update Parent Scope from Angular Directive with scope: true?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a need for inheriting scope from a parent controller in a directive.  I don't necessarily want to leave scope: false.  I also don't necessarily want to use an isolated scope, because it requires a lot of work to get the values I do care about linked properly (think lots of values in a parent controller).

Does it make sense to use `scope:true` in my directive if I want to update parent scope?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      Hello, {{name}}!
        <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Dave';
}


myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.updateName = function(newName) {
                console.log('newName is: ' + newName);
                scope.name = newName;
            }
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="updatedName" placeholder="new name value"> <button ng-click="updateName(updatedName)">Update</button>'
    }
})
```

Please check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binarygiant/8nGre/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Although @user1737909 already referenced the SO question to read ([What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), which will explain the problem and recommended various ways to fix it), we normally try to give the answer on SO.

So, the reason your fiddle doesn't work is because when a primitive type (i.e., a string, number, or boolean type) is written to -- e.g., `scope.name = newName` -- the "write" always goes to the local scope/object.  In other words, the child scope gets its own `name` property that shadows the parent property of the same name.  The fix is to use an object, rather than a primitive type, in the parent scope. The child scope will then get a reference to that object. Any writes to the object properties (whether from the parent or the child) will go to that one object.  (The child scope does not get its own object.)

```
$scope.obj = {name: 'Dave'};
```

Then in your directive:

```
scope.obj.name = newName;
```

and HTML:

```
Hello, {{obj.name}}!
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/c8pZs/)</kbd>

Comment: understanding only this part and not how scopes work more generally is imho not a good idea.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  This is the piece that glued it (or a large portion of it) together.  Thanks, Mark for the detailed answer, this is really great.

Comment: Sorry to dig an old thread but, in material-angular one can use for instance the mdSelect directive like this: <md-select ng-model="myprop" ... and myprop is updated with the currently selected value, even though it is a primitive. I had a look at the implementation

Comment: So how can this work? http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/ The directive overwrites show but the reference to modalShown is still kept.

Answer (score 15):

Scope inheritance is not meaning setting the value of a child is setting the value of its parent.

Instead of doing `scope.name = newName` on the child scope, add a method to the parent scope, which will do the same job but on the parent scope, and call it from the child scope since the child inherits this method.

Comment: This is what I went with, it seemed a cleaner to provide a setter method than allowing direct access to the properties of the parent scope.

Answer (score 6):

Within your link function you would write to the parent scope(the global "$scope" scope) like so: scope.$parent.name = newName;