# Angular directive does not update $scope.firstName

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that creates a button. When that button is clicked, it should update a variable `firstName` in the parent scope. I have already set `$scope.firstName = "Test"` in my controller.

The directive:

```
myApp.directive('myComponent', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      firstName: '='
    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      // A function that should update a parent scope variable.
      scope.changeName = function(){
        scope.firstName = "Name was changed."
      }
    }),

    template: '<button ng-click="changeName">Test</button>'
  };

});
```

firstName should change here when the button is clicked, but it does not. **Why does firstName not update?**

```
<div>
  {{ firstName }}
  <my-component first-name="firstName"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the [Directives angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), you can only use {{firstName}} inside the directory template in order to share the same scope. Check the documentation part about "Isolating the Scope of a Directive"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Using `'='` creates a reference to the object in the parent scope. Since it's a reference, when I set firstName equal to something else, it should be changed.

Comment: @DonnyP check this for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845605/is-it-possible-to-update-parent-scope-from-angular-directive-with-scope-true

Comment: One issue is that you aren't invoking `changeName` in your `ng-click` attr--you're just referencing it. You need the parens: `ng-click="changeName()"`

Comment: +1 to what @JAAulde said, you're not invoking `changeName`. Plunker for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/D3ad6Jkkjbl0ydAwHJj6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out '()' on ng-click.

```
   myApp.directive('myComponent', function(){
       return {
          scope: { firstName: '=' },
          template: '<button ng-click="changeName()">Test</button>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
               // A function that should update a parent scope variable.
                scope.changeName = function(){
             scope.firstName = "Name was changed."
          }
        }
      }
  });
```

Anyways, I have made a fiddle just to help you out. Check it and it is working fine. Revert me, if you have any other doubts. Link to fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/84Letr9o/3/