# Overwriting primitive value in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

According to the answer in [Is it Possible to Update Parent Scope from Angular Directive with scope: true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845605/is-it-possible-to-update-parent-scope-from-angular-directive-with-scope-true) it won't work to overwrite a primitive value in the parent scope from a directive since the reference is lost.

However, in this example that's exactly what's happening and the reference is kept:

http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/

http://output.jsbin.com/neluxejuwi

Directive JS:

```
scope: {
      show: '='
    },
[...]
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      [...]
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
```

HTML:

```
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='750px' height='90%'>
  <p>Modal Content Goes here<p>
</modal-dialog>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: *"it won't work to overwrite a primitive value in the parent scope"* you misunderstood the answer, it's correct and nothing mystical in observed behaviour. I recommend you to invest some time into good understanding of prototypical inheritance and how it works.